# Как обрезать данные из текстового файла?

Tags: логирование, linux

Имееться вот такой лог, из него мне нужны только ip, т.е SRC=, как можно сей лог укоротить и как выбрать только уникальную запись ну чтобы не повторялись, просто с люней не пока не сильно дружу, но видел как bash скриптами такое делали.

> `Feb  4 16:43:25 static enabled1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3c:65:ab:16:e2:ea:b1:d3:69:19:08:00 SRC=178.129.99.131 DST=78.46.249.243 LEN=52 TOS=00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=21548 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61654 DPT=3724 SEQ=2741525707 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0 
> Feb  4 16:43:26 static enabled1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3c:65:ab:16:e2:ea:b1:d3:69:19:08:00 SRC=178.129.99.131 DST=78.46.249.243 LEN=52 TOS=00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=21567 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61657 DPT=3724 SEQ=1141523393 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0 
> Feb  4 18:11:53 static enabled1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3c:65:ab:16:e2:ea:b1:d3:69:19:08:00 SRC=178.129.42.1 DST=78.46.249.243 LEN=52 TOS=00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=24478 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64190 DPT=3724 SEQ=3717923421 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0
> ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сходу родилось

```
grep -oE "SRC=[0-9.]+" ulogd_syslogemu.log | cut -d= -f2 | sort | uniq -с

 55 178.129.42.1
  2 178.129.99.131
```

-с  в самом конце - что бы видеть количество.

Comment: премного благодарен. =)